# Верстка в Google Chrome версии 37

Tags: google-chrome, html, вёрстка, css

Добрый день!

На днях обновился до Google Chrome версии 37. Сегодня захожу на сайт и наблюдаю, что у меня везде, где стоят блоки с `float: left`, поехала верстка. Причём это только в версии 37, в более старых всё нормально, в других браузерах тоже всё хорошо. Даже в ИЕ 7 всё хорошо. Кто знает, что там такого изменили в новой версии браузера?

Код примерно такой:

```
<div style="margin-left: -10px;">
  <div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-left: 10px;">Block 1</div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-left: 10px;">Block 2</div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-left: 10px;">Block 3</div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-left: 10px;">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

Размеры проставлены таким образом, чтобы блоки пиксель в пиксель умещались в ширину родительского блока с учётом маргинов.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

На скриншоте в ряд должно быть 3 картинки.

**Обновление**

P.S. Если у родительского блока строго задать ширину, тогда становится всё нормально. Т.е. если раньше ширина блока по умолчанию была 620 пикселей, то с `margin-left: -10px;` она становилась 630 пикселей. Выходит, что в новой версии это изменили, и теперь надо указывать ширину строго: `margin-left: -10px; width:` 630px;

Понял, что такой глюк возникает, когда макет 2-колоночный.
http://jsfiddle.net/2ysf6prx/1/
В старом хроме всё нормально, 3 колонки, а вот в новом - 2 колонки в строке. Если убрать этот div, то всё становится ок:
<div style="float: left; width: 180px; background-color: yellow;">s</div>

Answer (score 2):

Часто пользуюсь таким приёмом, у меня всё корректно. И ваш пример корректен тоже: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/2ysf6prx/

Comment: Понял, что такой глюк возникает, когда макет 2-колоночный.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ysf6prx/1/

В старом хроме всё нормально, 3 колонки, а вот в новом - 2 колонки в строке. Если убрать этот div, то всё становится ок:

<div style="float: left; width: 180px; background-color: yellow;">s</div>